# Python function that always return the same boolean value

Tags: python, functional-programming, return

In functional programming is sometimes *useful* to have a function that always return `True` (or `False`) for every parameter (or even multiple parameters).

Is there a built-in or a function defined in some module that have this exact behaviour?

Comment: I'm curious. Could you specify an example in which this would be useful? If, as in your answer, you have keywords that represent true or false, why do you need a function to take their place?

Comment: @Arc676: I'm using [`objgraph`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/objgraph) to view the memory graph. You can specify a function that defines if a node in the graph should be explored or not. I want *every* node to be explored, so now I'm using a lambda that always return `True`. This is only one case, but this is a pattern that I've seen a few times.

Comment: `object` returns an instance which will be *treated* as `True` in a Boolean context.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not aware of any built-in, but you can define them as:

```
false = lambda *_: False
true  = lambda *_: True
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the `*_`-syntax?

Comment: There is two things to elaborate on this syntax. First, the star is used to pass any number of arguments , usually noted `def myfunc(*args):` (works also with lambdas). A more correct version would use `(*args, **kwargs)` to also catch keywords arguments. The second thing to elaborate, is the use of unnamed variable `_` to indicate that we do not use the parameter. Hence, those lambda take any number of (nonkeywor) arguments and drops them all, which is what `*_` do.

Comment: @Jasper: DainDwarf is right, just one note: `_` is a valid variable identifier in python, and has no special syntactical (i.e., it does not drop anything), it is commonly used for variables that you don't care about, since nobody sane would ever write something like `_ + _ * _` instead of `x + x * x`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `object`, since its instances will always be treated as a true value, since `object` defines neither `__len__`, `__nonzero__` (in Python 2), nor `__bool__` (in Python 3).

```
>>> bool(object())
True
>>> if object():
...   print("Hi")
...
Hi
```

Comment: `object()` takes no parameters, so `bool(object(42))` raises an exception.

Comment: I apparently missed that part of the premise.