# Most pythonic callable generating True?

Tags: python, generator

The class [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=defaultdict#collections.defaultdict) takes a default factory, used to generate a default value.

If the values contained in the `dict`-like object should default to `False`, the instance can be created as:

```
d_false = defaultdict(bool)
```

What is the most pythonic way to achieve the same for a default value of `True`?

In other terms, is there a standard callable object returning `True` which is idiomatically used as the relative of `bool`?

Of course, the factory could be built as a lambda expression:

```
d_true = defaultdict(lambda: True)
```

but this might be reinventing the wheel.

Comment: `lambda: True` is fine as long as you don't need to pickle that defaultdict.

Comment: Hmm, I think all the builtin type constructors return a falsy value: `int() == 0`, `list() == []`, `str() == ''`, etc. So I don't think there's a standard way to do this.

Comment: The `lambda: value` construct is the idiomatic Pythonic way to construct a dict with a static default value; I know of no simpler way to get a function returning `True`.

Comment: Related: [Python function that always return the same boolean value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34901831/4518341)

Comment: Following my earlier comment, turns out [`object()` is truthy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34903391/4518341) -- not sure if that's useful

Comment: I wouldn't say `defaultdict(bool)` is too pythonic. It's not *immediately* clear what's happening there, as it would be with `lambda: False`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, you can do

```
d = defaultdict(True.__bool__)
```

but I personally would go with the `lambda: True`.

Comment: As @Aran-Frey said above, you can't `pickle` a defaultdict with a lambda; so if that's a consideration, `True.__bool__` is the way to go. But it's definitely an uglier solution. (Also, not available in Python 2.x, which probably doesn't matter much with only a month until it goes EOL...)

Answer (score 5):

We could use `partial` as an alternative to `lambda`:

```
from functools import partial
from collections import defaultdict

d_true = defaultdict(partial(bool, True))

print(d_true['bona fide'])
```

(Which is also Python 2 friendly.)

Answer (score 3):

If you just want a "truthy" value, you could use `object`; that constructor returns an object which evaluates as true in a boolean context. But if you want the actual boolean value `True`, I don't know of a better way than the `lambda: True` construct.

As Aran-Frey said above, though, you can't `pickle` a defaultdict whose factory is a `lambda`; if that's a consideration, I would go with Andrej Kesely's solution of `True.__bool__`.

Answer (score 0):

## The most pythonic way to do is...

drum rolls

```py
lambda: True
```

Please don't use `True.__bool__`! That's not pythonic!